# Solidus Paypal Braintree Integration Not Working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, spree, braintree-sandbox, solidus

Using a sandbox account, I have been trying to integrate solidus_paypal_braintree with my app.

Clicking the PayPal Checkout button brings up the PayPal window, without payment details. Then static control is returned to the app.

What am I missing here? Is there additional necessary setup to include webhooks or token?

Please see this video for more information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=nRXx90zF6BY

Answer (score 1):

Address was invalid because, phone_required? was set to true.